# Android: show/hide system bar like Netflix app

Tags: android

I've built a simple video player app for Android 4.2. I'd like to be able to programmatically show/hide the system bar while this app is playing video. I've read many threads here that indicate a device must be rooted in order to hide the system bar.

Then, I noticed that the Netflix app on my un-rooted Android tablet achieves the effect I'm after:

1. When the Netflix app is first launched, thee system bar is shown.
2. 5 seconds after a video starts playing, the system bar icons slide down and are hidden.
3. Tapping the screen causes the system bar icons to slide back into view.
4. 5 seconds later, the system bar icons slide out of view again.

How might I achieve this effect?

Comment: Should be quite simple, when video is started set a timer to hide statusbar, when receiving touch in the videoview show it, and set the timer again. shouldnt be too hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `setSystemUiVisibility()` (See [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility%28int%29)).

Specifically the [SYSTEM_UI_*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE) flags. In KitKat, they've added additional flags for [immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html).

Comment: I'm currently doing this: videoView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE); -- This causes each icon on hte system bar to display as a dot. That's good. But the first time the user touches the screen, the icons reappear and stay for as long as the app runs.

Comment: If you look at the linked example, you have to set yourself as a listener for UI visibility changes and then set the flags back after user interaction.